# Using the IN clause with Java's JCR-SQL2

Tags: java, jcr, magnolia, jcr-sql2

I am trying to use an 'IN' clause with Magnolia with JCR-SQL2:

```
SELECT * FROM [mgnl:page]
WHERE [mgnl:template] IN (
    "context:pages/template-type-1", 
    "context:pages/template-type-2"
)
```

However I'm receiving this error:

```
SELECT * FROM [mgnl:page]
WHERE [mgnl:template] IN(*)("context:pages/template-type-1","context:pages/template-type-2");
expected: ., =, <>, <, >, <=, >=, LIKE, IS, NOT
```

Is this caused by the fact my implementation of the JCR does not support the IN clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a quick research about it and turned out that the in JCR specification WHERE IN clause  is not listed and its possible with some extensions.

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/content_repository-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/

So, you already answered yourself that its not supported in the version you are currently using.

Cheers,